# How to read elliptic curve public key from DER file with OpenSSL in C

Tags: c, openssl

What is the correct OpenSSL C API function to read an elliptic curve public key in DER format that has already been read into a byte array?

The key was generated via the following command line arguments:

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out private.der -outform der
openssl ec -in private.der -pubout -out public.der -outform der
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `d2i_PUBKEY` for this purpose. See the man page here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/d2i_PUBKEY.html